# Will Flattr support Bitcoin?

Tags: services, spending

It would be great if it would be possible to spend Bitcoins via [Flattr](http://flattr.com/). Does anybody know if there is something planed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your timing is perfect. [Yesterday Flattr announced](http://blog.flattr.net/2013/07/adding-bitcoin-support/) that they were going to implement Bitcoin.